# .py file is not compiled on django

Tags: django

I'm using django 1.6.1. I got one file name "payment.py" on models folder and it's not compiled to .pyc file. Even if I changed the file name to "payment_room.py", it still won't be compiled

The other model files have been compiled already and worked pretty well.

Because of that, django won't create the table on my database if I run syncdb command. I run validate command using manage.py, but it didn't return any error.

N.B.
It's still on debug & development mode. The web hasn't been deployed to apache server yet.

```
from django.db import models
from ghb_manager.models.reservation import Reservation

class Payment (models.Model):
    class Meta:
        app_label = 'ghb_manager'

    PAYMENT_METHOD_CHOICES = (
    ('CA', 'Cash'),
    ('CR', 'Credit'),
    ('TR', 'Transfer')
    )

    payment_id = models.CharField(max_length=14, primary_key=True)
    reservation_id = models.ForeignKey(Reservation)
    ammount_tendered = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=2)
    payment_method = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=PAYMENT_METHOD_CHOICES)
    payment_date = models.DateField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.payment_id
```

Comment: can you post "payment.py" here?

Comment: I just put the snapshot on question

Comment: Is the app in INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: Yes, it is. I have created other 20 models on 'ghb_manager' application and it's compiled already & work well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check your **init**.py in your models directory. You have to import all the models you create in models directory, like:

```
# __init__.py
from payment import Payment
```

Django looks into app.models for app's models.

Comment: I have other files that I haven't registered on __init__.py and it's still compiled. Is it happened because of foreign key relationship?

Comment: Probably Yes, 2 things are important when you want to break your models.py. 1. Entry in init.py and 2. "app_label" in meta class.