# Django Production Deployment : Should we not remove source files ?

Tags: python, django, mod-wsgi

Hi I am a newbie to Django AND Python. Working currently on a dummy project using Django 1.9. So following the excellent Django Documentation I could complete the deployment using apache/mod_wsgi and it is running on a test web server on my local machine.

But I am wondering about the Python source files  :

I have given the path to my development directory - say **/Python-labs/mysite/** to mod_wsgi and apache configuration ( httpd.conf ) files. This development directory obviously contains all the .py files - the Python source files.

No-where in the documentation i found any mention to remove the source files etc. So I googled but could not get anything as a standard step to remove source files from the production deployment. 
Got this - the closest to what I am asking for :

[Django Remove Source Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4311265/django-remove-source-files-and-generate-pyc-files)

[Django Deployment Without Source Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15828148/how-to-deploy-django-server-into-production-environment-without-a-full-source-co)

but again it does not make it crystal clear about the questions below :

My Questions :

1. Is it a standard step in Django deployment to remove source files or not ?
   ( or Did I miss something very obvious from the documentation ? )
2. Is it Ok if we put .py files on production server ? Or is it intended that way ?

Thanks a lot in Advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is typical to deploy source files with Django. As long as the project is set properly (`__init__.py` included for all project/app directories) then Django will compile `.py` files to `.pyc`.

To answer your questions - 
 1. Don't serve your production files directly; use a good VCS to push files to your production server or, if quick and dirty, copy your project to your production server. But uncompiled `.py` files are standard for most Django projects.
 2. Yes.

For more insight, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21326797/py-file-is-not-compiled-on-django) may help.

Comment: Thanks for the help and clarification ! Really appreciated ! And yes i will use some VCS for pushing the files to Production.

Comment: One thing I'd like to add... .pyc files are created on module import. Essentially this only happens once per file (per version) at the time that Django starts running.